# Computing GrayLevelCooccurrenceMatrix

Tags: c#, grayscale

I have a BMP image that is grayscale. I need to find the gray level cooccurrence matrix for the bmp image.

I know it uses accord.imaging name space. But there aren't any instructions on how to compute the matrix value. I have already converted the image into unmanaged image as i have seen that the compute function uses only unmanaged images.

```
public double[,] Compute(
    UnmanagedImage source
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at Accord documentation:
http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Imaging_GrayLevelCooccurrenceMatrix.htm

It says you should create an instance of

```
 var matrix = Accord.Imaging.GrayLevelCooccurrenceMatrix
```

and then call

```
double[,] grayValues = matrix.Compute(UnmanagedImage)
```